# How to remove Space at the bottom of TextField in flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

[image: Dialog]

I can't figure out why there is space at the bottom of `TextField` between the text and the blue line.

Here is my code :

```
Future<Null> _selectNoteType (BuildContext context) async {

  switch (await showDialog<Null>(

      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {

        return new SimpleDialog(

          title: const Text('Select Note Type'),
          children: <Widget>[

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
              child: new TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                maxLines: 1,
                style: new TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 20.0
                ),
              ),
            ),

            new SimpleDialogOption(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text('Text')
              ),

            new SimpleDialogOption(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Text('Checklist')
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
  )) {}
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a collapsed `InputDecoration` for the `decoration:` property of the `TextField`.

```
  Future<Null> _selectNoteType(BuildContext context) async {

    InputDecoration decoration = const InputDecoration.collapsed()
      ..applyDefaults(Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme);

    switch (await showDialog<Null>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return new SimpleDialog(
            title: const Text('Select Note Type'),
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                child: new TextField(
                  decoration: decoration,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
              ),
              new SimpleDialogOption(
                  onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Text')),
              new SimpleDialogOption(
                  onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Checklist')),
            ],
          );
        })) {
    }
  }
```

But you must know the consequences of using a collapsed `InputDecoration`. From the documentation:

```
  /// Whether the decoration is the same size as the input field.
  ///
  /// A collapsed decoration cannot have [labelText], [errorText], an [icon].
  ///
  /// To create a collapsed input decoration, use [InputDecoration..collapsed].
  final bool isCollapsed;
```

And for the `InputDecoration.collapse()` constructor:

```
  /// Defines an [InputDecorator] that is the same size as the input field.
  ///
  /// This type of input decoration does not include a border by default.
  ///
  /// Sets the [isCollapsed] property to true.
  const InputDecoration.collapsed({
```

Answer (score 38):

In my case the `TextField` would still not collapse even after using `InputDecoration.collapsed()`.

My version doesn't have any padding at all and takes the minimum size:

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
    isDense: true,
    border: InputBorder.none,
  ),
  minLines: 1,
  maxLines: 1,
);
```

[image: Example preview]

Live preview:
https://dartpad.dev/3f9149a1c8f5eec352c796e7585e233c

Comment: Works perfect for me :)

Comment: what if you have a suffix or prefix Icon this wont work in that case

Comment: @maheshmnj What do you mean? Just add the to a Row widget.

Comment: I believe that this is the more appropriate solution and should be the accepted answer!

Comment: Be aware of this bug if you are also targeting Web https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/86093

Answer (score 5):

**isDense** will do the trick. uses less vertical space

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    isDense: true,
  ),
);
```