# Cannot remove underside padding from TextField and TextFormField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this widget:

```
TextFormField(
  controller: _activityName,
  autocorrect: true,
  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding = EdgeInsets.zero,



      border: UnderlineInputBorder(

      ),

      hintText: ""),
  maxLines: 1,
  cursorColor: Colors.white,
),
```

As you can see I explicitly set the padding to be 0, as this answer said:
[How do I remove content padding from TextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53644897/how-do-i-remove-content-padding-from-textfield)

But the result I get is this:

[image]

As you can see under the Text MyActivity there is a lot of padding, but I can't get rid of it.
It looks like a bug, but I'm not sure:

This is the flutter doctor:

```
Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.295], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 %Flutter path%
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (3 weeks ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0
```

Comment: The padding is said to be intentional. Source: [flutter issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15483#issuecomment-372864415).

Comment: @Harshvardhan Joshi So I cannot remove it in any way?

Comment: I don't think so. because I have tried and every possible padding value in TextField to zero and it still has the same padding.

Comment: @HarshvardhanJoshi Ah ok, Thank you for taking your time to help me! Let's hope for a fix soon!

Comment: if you saw the issue, they said it's intended. so maybe we can ask for an optional "compensation" parameter to remove extra padding.

Comment: That would be a great idea

Comment: This is marked as `severe: regression` in this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46160), It might take few months for this fix...

Answer (score 16):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/59295394/4465386 - check it out for a demo too.

This is how to get 0 padding textFields:

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
    isDense: true,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove a little bit of space by using collapsed:

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: null),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    isDense: true,
  ),
);
```