# How to remove the space between SpinBox content and underline?

Tags: css, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

My question is essentially the same as [How to remove Space at the bottom of TextField in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52577883/how-to-remove-space-at-the-bottom-of-textfield-in-flutter), except instead of a TextFormField widget, I am asking the same for a SpinBox widget. Setting `isDense: true` or `isCollapsed: true` seems to move the number out of line with the increment/decrement buttons (see screenshots)

[image: isDense: true]

Meanwhile, wrapping in a `SizedBox` and setting height is some improvement, but I am not able to shrink height as much as I would like, or increment/decrement go below the line.
This is with a height of 25:

[image: Height 25]

Having a height of 45 looks visually fine but it takes up too much space for my needs.

Current code which produces the layout below:

```
SizedBox(
  width: 120,
  height: 45,
  child: SpinBox(
    value: 0,
    onChanged: (value) {}
  ),
)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you include your-code snippet that will reproduce the same issue ?

Comment: `SpinBox` is not a standard widget. In such cases, always include link to library containing it - there could be multiple `SpinBox` implementations with different behaviour out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/jpnurmi/flutter_spinbox/blob/main/lib/src/material/spin_box.dart) of the `SpinBox` you can see that you have the `inputDecoration` of the `TextField` exposed, and you can try removing the `contentPadding` of it and see if it fixes your issue :

```dart
SpinBox(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  ),
);
```